# Storing functions in dataframe in R

Tags: r, bayesian, tibble

I am doing some bayesian analysis and have empirical distributions for many features (that is, one distribution for each feature). I want to store the feature indices, **their distribution functions** and some other information **in a data frame or a tibble**, one row for each feature, for convenience of further usage.

But I think `data.frame` or `tibble` function in R won't allow functions as their input. Is there an alternative way to save those as a dataframe-type structure?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can save functions in a list `list(mean, sd, \(x) x^3)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do store those functions as part of a data.table or tibble, like with this example:

```
data.table(id=c(1,2,3), dist_funcs = list(pnorm, ppois, pbinom))
```

Output:

```
      id    dist_funcs
   <num>        <list>
1:     1 <function[1]>
2:     2 <function[1]>
3:     3 <function[1]>
```

Similarly with tibbles:

```
tibble(id=c(1,2,3), dist_funcs = list(pnorm, ppois,pbinom))
```

Output:

```
     id dist_funcs
  <dbl> <list>    
1     1 <fn>      
2     2 <fn>      
3     3 <fn>
```

Comment: it works with `tibble` too. to make it work with data frames do : `df$fun_col <- function_list`,

Answer (score 0):

You can store functions in a list:

```
> list(mean, median)
[[1]]
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("mean")
<bytecode: 0x000002b3fdfb77d0>
<environment: namespace:base>

[[2]]
function (x, na.rm = FALSE, ...) 
UseMethod("median")
<bytecode: 0x000002b3f95dd3f8>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```